# Uniform position for multiple components

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

(Modified from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3730261/uniform-position-theorem-for-reducible-varieties/3730457#3730457)

The uniform position theorem states (roughly) that a general hyperplane section meets an irreducible degree $d$ curve $C \subset \mathbb{P}^r$ at $d$ points with any $r$ of them being independent (e.g. see general/uniform position theorems around section III.1 in vol. I of "Geometry of Algebraic Curves").

Is there a version of this when we remove the "irreducible" condition? For example, what happens if we consider points coming from some collection of disjoint irreducible curves? Note that this excludes cases such as some large number of curves lying in some hyperplane (or others similar to what was mentioned in the MSE link).

This seems plausible for many cases, but I'm not sure how to put this into a coherent statement and irreducibility seems to be an important part of proving this theorem. In principle, one could imagine applying the theorem to each irreducible component and taking an intersection of some finite number of open sets (see link on top). However, it seems like this intersection may be empty (e.g. in the "degenerate" examples in the second paragraph). Also, are the counterexamples of the kind mentioned above the only ones possible?